# Wordpress Website issue

Tags: seo

I have my website in WordPress. Now the problem is if I search any keywords in Google related to website webpages then it doesn't show any webpage result in web results. But if I search in Google blog result then It is showing my webpages in Google blog results.

I want to know what is problem with my webpages. Why they are coming in Google blog search instead of Google web search?

Comment: you will need to supply your blog url if you want anyone to be able to look at it.

Comment: here is my url http://www.openxcell.com

Comment: nothing wrong as far as I can see, you will have to consult the google webmaster tools, or ask in an SEO related stack.

Comment: Your website is ranking within Google's normal search, your just not ranking that well compared to that of your blog on their blog search. You need to increase your Google's Search Results, I've linked relevant question and answers on how to increase Google rankings.